# No unity on log in after update

Tags: 14.04, unity, 14.10

I recently did what ended up being a do-release-upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10 from Ubuntu 14.10. I had to go into recovery mode and run the repair utilities to finish the update.

The problem I'm having is now when I log in my computer hangs or just doesn't load unity so I can use my laptop. I can't even open a terminal window with cal alt T.

Can anyone advise me on how I can go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this is easy, to solve a bit less so...

Boot your Ubuntu Live CD, double-click on the system partition icon and have a look at

```
/media/ubuntu/SomeWeirdNumber/var/log/syslog
```

and

```
/media/ubuntu/SomeWeirdNumber/var/log/kern.log
```

There you will find most information to trouble-shoot this.

Comment: When I try to sart xorg, I get the following error could not create lock file in /temp/.tx0-lock giving up unable to connect to x server connection refused

Comment: When does this happen?  When you try to boot the LiveCD? When you double-click on the System partition?  I'm confused now...  ;-)